# Trouble centering text within an image

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble trying to find a way to make the text appear at the center of the image using flexbox method. I've tried using position: relative to the container class .top-content and position: relative to the child .top-content h2, h4. But the text just gets above each other.

```css
.top-content {
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
}

.top-image {
  border: 1px solid seashell;
  height: 700px;
  width: 1200px;
  margin-top: 69px;
  z-index: 0;
}

.top-content h2,
h4 {
  color: seashell;
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header">
    <img class="tea-cozy-logo" src="resources/images/img-tea-cozy-logo.png" alt="tea cozy logo" />
    <div class="header-links">
      <h3>Mission</h3>
      <h3>Featured Tea</h3>
      <h3>Locations</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="top-content">
  <img class="top-image" src="resources/images/img-mission-background.jpg" alt="pot of tea leaves" />
  <h2>Our Mission</h2>
  <h4>
    Handipicked, Artisanally Curated, Free Range, Sustainable, Small Batch, Fair Trade, Organic Tea
  </h4>
</div>
```

Comment: So you want the "Our misson" and the "Handipicked ..." paragraph to be displayed on the "img-mission-background.jpg" image?

Comment: It's unclear what you want. You'll need to explain better. In the mean time some infos: You speak of the "flexbox method", however nowhere in your CSS is `display: flex` (`align-*` and `justify-*` properties do nothing without `display: flex` or `grid`). If those are supposted to be background images, then they should actulaly be background images in the CSS and not HTML content images.

Comment: @Joshua Yes, that's what I was trying to do. What I ended up doing was setting `display: flex`, `align-content` and `justify-content` to the center of the page on the **.top-content** class just as @RoToRa suggested. After that I used the property `position: relative` for the background image and `position: absolute` for the texts.

Comment: @RoToRa I actually didn't know that you should set the background images in the CSS content. Thanks for the tip!